# Algorithms for Degree and Distance positioning system

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I'm working on a positioning system which using matrixes can not satisfy my needs. so I decided to use a system based on **Degree and Distance positioning**. 
I never heard or worked with such a system(maybe because I gave up university to start my business as a freelancer). but it seems useful in game programming,3d engines and other stuff. so my question is:

> *What is the name of this system?*

and as I need many algorithms and resources to complete my work Any resources tutorials  introduction is appreciated.

for example I'll need an algorithm to see ***How much is the degree and distance of o1 from o2?***

```
   o1(Degree=45,distance=3)
    \  |
     \ |
      \|(0,0)
_______o_______
       |\
       | \
       |  o2(Degree=225,distance=2)
       |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the name of this system?

The system you're thinking of is [*polar coordinates*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinates).

These express a position in terms of radius *r* and angle *theta*.

You can convert from Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates as follows:

```
r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
theta = atan2(y, x)
```

---

> for example I'll need an algorithm to see How much is the degree and distance of o1 from o2

Polar coordinates aren't much good for this.  You just need straightforward trigonometry.